# PC does not start after 'autoremove' and 'do-release-upgrade'

Tags: boot, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I made an attempt to upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04 following the steps on [this site][1] https://blog.eldernode.com/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-22-04/. At the step "do-release-upgrade" the system asked me to reboot first, which I did. However, the PC is completely not responding anymore. When I start it I don't get the bios splash screen nor the grub (?) menu where I normally can choose the operating system (I have dual boot). Also I can't enter the bios menu. All I get is a black screen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Upgrades from 18.04 are only available to the next release (18.10 but that [ceased being an option when 18.10 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/)), or to the next LTS which is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I opened that link you provided and it looks like a bad *hack* to me, not written but I suspect the author grabbed a prior article & replaced some details but not others. I'd not have used it given the incorrect details within it. I'd suggest using *official* Ubuntu guides in future as you've chosen an *unsupported* path

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get the BIOS splash screen, then you have a motherboard fault unrelated to Ubuntu or your release-upgrade.

Such faults are not caused by Ubuntu, nor by the process of a release-upgrade. Coincidence. It happens.

Ubuntu cannot repair nor compensate for hardware faults. You must repair (or replace) your hardware before you can do anything else with that system.